# I am getting error in plotly module of FB prophet

Tags: python, plotly, facebook-prophet

I am getting the following error when executing the below code:

Code:
`from fbprophet.plot import plot_plotly, plot_components_plotly`

Error:
`Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.`

Comment: Please use the right mark down for code sample.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 17):

run `pip install --upgrade plotly`

It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

From the fb-prophet quickstart [website](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html):

> An interactive figure of the forecast and components can be created with plotly. You will need to install plotly 4.0 or above separately, as it will not by default be installed with prophet. You will also need to install the notebook and ipywidgets packages.

While I don't have too much experience with using interactive graphs in prophet, [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-prediction-using-prophet-in-python-35d65f626236) just did a quick installation using pip install plotly, so let me know if that helps.